# Robocopy /Purge /Move - at what point/how will destination folders/files be deleted?

Tags: windows, robocopy

I have read both [At what point does Robocopy overwrite a file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1080763/at-what-point-does-robocopy-overwrite-a-file) and [At what point does Robocopy overwrite a file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1080763/at-what-point-does-robocopy-overwrite-a-file), and neither seem to address my question or I'm totally clueless. Example(s):

- **Parent-Dir:** Zip Code
- **Multiple sub-dir** *(each day)***:** `yyyymmdd`
- **Sample filename:** `1_IPC1_NAPA_20240202001334.mp4` 
   *(there can be an average of 5,000 MP4 files per folder)*

With both the src and dest having less than 500GB of free space, I run:

```
Robocopy A:\Parent_Dir B:\Parent_Dir /PURGE /MOVE
```

- I'm not clear\sure if that command will `/PURGE` as needed, all at once, or try and write new data before it performs `/PURGE` on anything
- I have used `/L` attempting to get a clue, but it only lists what's marked for deletion, not when during the processes, the marked item is deleted

Comment: This might explain it : https://superuser.com/questions/1522346/how-to-let-robocopy-remove-extra-file-first